# Apple Push Notification test app

Tags: ios, testing, apple-push-notifications

I'm implementing APN functionality at the server side but I don't have the app to get the token from and send notification to. Is there any tool/app that has already implemented the push notification and can give me the token so I can test the server?

Answer (score 0):

In order to send push notifications to your users, it is up to you to store each user's device token in your own database. Then you can address a message to each user, send the message payload to Apple, and Apple will send the message to the user.

In the past I used [PushMeBaby](https://github.com/Dwarven/PushMeBaby) during iOS Push Notification development to push notifications on the device from the Mac. There is also an [online tool](http://pushmebaby.herokuapp.com/) to test your notifications.

Also there is NWPusher at github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher

Comment: Thanks but these are all server-side implementations. I already have that. I want a dummy client app on my iPhone that is capable of receiving the push notification so I can test my server functionality.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry about the confusion. Then try this solution: https://github.com/wsvn53/Cocoa-APNS-Test

Answer (score 0):

simple use application **APN tester free** on app store

give .cer file and device token